# Uniting many rows into one (R)

Tags: r

I have data formatted in the following way

```
-------------------------
| A | a |            1   |
-------------------------
| A | a |            2   |
-------------------------
| A | a |            3   |
-------------------------
| B | b |            1   |
-------------------------
| B | b |            3   |
-------------------------
| B | b |            5   |
-------------------------
```

Basically, if the first key is the same, all  the columns except the last one are the same. I want to make the data-frame more compact and make it so instead of one observation per instance of the last column, I have a list of numbers

Something like this:

```
-------------------------
| A | a |        1,2,3   |
-------------------------
| B | b |        1,3,5   |
-------------------------
```

I am learning the tidyverse in R, but I am very new and I have not been able to find the right function to do this yet. I appreciate any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) list** This makes the third column a list such that each element of the list contains a vector.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
  group_by(V1, V2) %>%
  nest %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  V1    V2    data            
  <fct> <fct> <list>          
1 A     a     <tibble [3 x 1]>
2 B     b     <tibble [3 x 1]>
```

**1a)** This can also be written

```
DF %>% nest(V3, .key = "V3")
```

**2) character** Another possibility would be to create strings out of the data in the third column:

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  group_by(V1, V2) %>%
  summarize(V3 = toString(V3)) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  V1    V2    V3     
  <fct> <fct> <chr>  
1 A     a     1, 2, 3
2 B     b     1, 3, 5
```

**3) sql** The above used dplyr.  This uses SQL to give an answer similar to (2).

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select V1, V2, group_concat(V3) V3 
       from DF
       group by V1, V2", method = "raw")
```

giving:

```
  V1 V2    V3
1  A  a 1,2,3
2  B  b 1,3,5
```

### Note

In the future please provide the data in reproducible form like this:

```
Lines <- "
A | a |            1
A | a |            2
A | a |            3
B | b |            1
B | b |            3
B | b |            5"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks, that works great! I will be more careful in the future about the format of the data

Comment: Added (3) and (1a)

Answer (score 5):

Group by your ID column, and summarize the number column using paste (with `collapse=","`). That will give you a (character) column with the list of numbers for each ID row.

```
require(dplyr)
df<-data.frame(a=c("a","a","a","b","b"),b=c(1,2,3,1,2))
df %>% group_by(a) %>% summarize(b=paste(b,collapse=","))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  a     b      
  <fct> <chr>  
1 a     1,2,3
2 b     1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using R base:

```
> aggregate(V3~V1+V2, data=DF, paste0, collapse=",")
  V1 V2    V3
1  A  a 1,2,3
2  B  b 1,3,5
```